# How to update a Filenet document's content without changing the version?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I am trying to change document content and save the changes into current version itself without increment the document version number using filenet java API.

Any one help me on this topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delete, make changes to the document and recreate the same with updated content is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Changing content always leads to the creation of a new version. It is not possible to directly accomplish what you want.

If you need the version number intact, delete the current version and save the changes. Then create a new version.

Answer (score 1):

As fnt said, the main goal of an ECM platform is to guarantee that a version content stays unchanged. The only thing doable, is to update as much times as you need [the content of the checked out version](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.cews.doc/examples/documentcontent_ex.htm?lang=en) (reservation). That can be useful for a Save (without CheckIn scenario). Don't know if that is useful to you. If not, you need to delete/re-create a new version to keep the same version number.